# Remove json specific data if date is in the past or future

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to add upcoming classes and past classes components in my application. I am able to store classes schedule and then get them using services from backend but i want to show only upcoming classes in the upcoming classes component and classes that are in the past in the past classes component. This is what i have done so far. How can i compare the classes and then remove them from the json list that i am getting on frontend side

html

```
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor = "let completeData of schedule">
   <td class="trim">{{completeData.date | date}}</td>
   <td class="trim">{{completeData.course}}</td>
   <td class="trim">{{completeData.location}}</td>
   <td class="trim">{{completeData.instructor}}</td>
   <td class="trim"><nb-checkbox [(ngModel)]="completeData.listing"></nb-checkbox></td>  
   <td class="trim">
    <nb-select>
     <nb-option value="2">Edit</nb-option>
     <nb-option value="3">Delete</nb-option>
     <nb-option value="4" (click)="viewDetails()">View</nb-option>
    </nb-select>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

component.ts file

```
schedule: ClassSchedule = new ClassSchedule();
ngOnInit() {
this._classService.GetClassData()
.subscribe((result: any) => {
  this.schedule = result;
})
}
```

interface for schedule

```
export interface IClassSchedule {
    course: string | undefined;    
    date: string | undefined;
    hour: string | undefined;
    minute: string | undefined;
    timeofday:  string | undefined;
    totalHours: string | undefined;
    //Other fields not added here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function that will split the past and upcoming schedules:

```
/*
  Takes an array of items and returns an object with past and upcoming items
*/
function groupByDate(items: any[]): { past: any[]; upcoming: any[] } {
  const today = Date.now();
  const initial: { past: any[]; upcoming: any[] } = {
    past: [],
    upcoming: []
  };

  return items.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const itemDate = new Date(curr.date).getTime();
    const isPast = itemDate < today;

    return {
      past: isPast ? [...prev.past, curr] : prev.past,
      upcoming: !isPast ? [...prev.upcoming, curr] : prev.upcoming
    };
  }, initial);
```

Attached is a stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-group-by-date) of how to use this with your observable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [partition](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html) to split it into two observables.

```
ngOnInit() {
  const currentTimestamp = Date.now();
  const [futureCourses$, pastCourses$] = this._classService.GetClassData()
    .pipe(partition( item => item.timestamp > currentTimestamp ));

  futureCourses$.subscribe((result) => {
    // Here is the future ones
  })

  pastCourses$.subscribe((result) => {
    // Here is the past ones
  })
}
```

The example assumes that you can get the timestamp, to make it easier for comparison. If you can't get it, then you can use [moment](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment) for easier comparisons.

Comment: that's a very good approach but you see in my interface date has a data type of string and to show it on page i am making use of "date pipe" so can i avoid making use of timestamp or is it necessary?

Comment: and what is this partition?

Comment: This is nice!! Learnt a new operator

Comment: @ahsannissar if the date is a timestamp, then yes you can use it instead of `item.timestamp`. It will be `item.date`. The partition operator is used to split an observable into two depending on a condition. You can refer to the link I added.